# Three js and react button above canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, three.js, onclick

this is my three.js code in react, I want to add button above this canvas..
How can I do??
Also, How can I add click event on my object?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import * as THREE from 'three'
    //import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

    class Scene extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.start = this.start.bind(this)
    this.stop = this.stop.bind(this)
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    const sizes = {
        width : window.innerWidth,
        height : window.innerHeight
    }

    const scene = new THREE.Scene()

    window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
    {
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    })

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10 );
    const particlesGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    const particlesCnt = 8000;

    const posArray = new Float32Array(particlesCnt * 3);

    for (let i=0; i< particlesCnt *3; i++) {
    posArray[i] = (Math.random() - 0.5 ) *5
    }

    particlesGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(posArray, 3));
    
    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        size: 0.005
    })

    // Texture Loader
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
    const star = loader.load('./star.png')
    const particlesMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        size: 0.005,
        map: star,
        transparent: true,
        //color: 'blue'
        //bleding: THREE.AdditiveBlending
    })
    
    const cube = new THREE.Points(geometry, material)
    const particlesMesh = new THREE.Points(particlesGeometry, particlesMaterial);
    scene.add(cube, particlesMesh)

    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
    pointLight.position.x = 2
    pointLight.position.y = 3
    pointLight.position.z = 4
    scene.add(pointLight)

    //camera.position.z = 4
    // scene.add(cube)
    // renderer.setClearColor('#000000')

    
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width /sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
    camera.position.x = 0
    camera.position.y = 0
    camera.position.z = 2
    scene.add(camera)

    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)

    this.scene = scene
    this.camera = camera
    this.renderer = renderer
    this.material = material
    this.cube = cube
    this.particlesMesh = particlesMesh

    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    this.start()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop()
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    }

    start() {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    }
    }

    stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId)
    }

    animate() {
    //this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01
    this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01
    this.particlesMesh.rotation.y += 0.01

    this.renderScene()
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    
    }

    renderScene() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: '400px', height: '400px' }}
        ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}
      >
          </div>
    )
    }
    }

    export default Scene
```

this is my three.js code in react, I want to add button above this canvas..
How can I do??
Also, How can I add click event on my object in threejs?

Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest taking a look at react-three/fiber and react-three/drei to speed up development, when using react and three.

The button issue: To make the button appear you should look at your styling. For example you could set the position of the button to `absolute` and the zIndex to a value larger than the canvas.

e.g.

```
<div style={{
 position: "absolute",
 top: "50%",
 left: "50%",
 zIndex: "10000"
}}>
 <Button >
</div>
```

Click event issue: To listen to a click event on an 3d object you have to implement an [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster)

Then you will be able to check for intersections with objects in your scene and  call additional function.

react-three/fiber already implemented this feature for you and you can just call:

```
<mesh
 onClick={(e) => // do something}>
</mesh>
```